VS Code Java's Scanner doesn't recognise special characters
I have been using VSCode to program in Java but I am having a problem with special characters, When entering a String with a special character using the Scanner, or reading it from a file, VS Code does not recognize it, However, if I do a System.out.println("á, é, í, ó, ú); Java does recognize it without problems
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("System.out.print -> á, é, í, ó, ú");

System.out.print("Input -> ");
String i = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Output -> " + i);

Java Output
I tried with Python, in this case everything works just fine, it recognize the special characters.
i = input("Input-> ")

print("Output-> ", i)

Python Output
Same with Eclipse, in this IDE everything works without any problem.
I already checked the settings with VS Code, UTF-8 is the default option.

Do you see different results if you create your Scanner using new Scanner(System.console().reader())?

@VGR this works perfectly! Do you know any way to make it work without using the objetc console?
I guess this is the only solution without an IDE

The problem is the charset.  Setting VSCode to UTF-8 only tells the compiler what the charset of your source file is.  Your own program needs to tell the Scanner which charset to use when reading System.in.  Console.reader() uses the underlying system’s charset and returns a Reader based on it.  You can do something similar using new Scanner(System.in, System.getProperty("native.encoding")).
